# How to reduce an algorithm into smaller parts so I can scale it?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have updated this question(found last question not clear, if you want to refer to it check out the reversion history). The current answers so far do not work because I failed to explain my question clearly(sorry, second attempt).

**Goal**:

Trying to take a set of numbers(pos or neg, thus needs bounds to limit growth of specific variable) and find their linear combinations that can be used to get to a specific sum. For example, to get to a sum of 10 using [2,4,5] we get:

```
 5*2 +  0*4 +  0*5 = 10
 3*2 +  1*4 +  0*5 = 10
 1*2 +  2*4 +  0*5 = 10
 0*2 +  0*4 +  2*5 = 10
```

How can I create an algo that is scalable for large number of variables and target_sums? I can write the code on my own if an algo is given, but if there's a library avail, I'm fine with any library but prefer to use java.

Comment: With the information you have provided, it is only possible to determine if what you did is correct/fast or wrong. If you want an alternate algorithm, you would have to provide the entire problem statement. Hope you get what I am trying to say.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by if `T[z-c*x_i][i-1]` is true? What kind of array is `T[][]`?

Comment: @noMAD So far, I'm looking for a way of breaking this algo down but if I don't get any responses or this is impossible to scale I may repost a question to improve the entire algo. I'm posting a specific example, but honestly I think I'll run into similar issues again so I'd rather understand general principles so I can apply to other situations..T is just a key/val table T[0][0] or T[10][2],etc..

Comment: I realise you are looking for algorithmic improvements, but your ultimate goal here is to speed up some code, and it is perfectly possible that looking at your implementation would be more fruitful - maybe you could tell us what language you are working in, what the type of `T` is, and give us some actual code.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I assume that there will be far fewer `true` values in your matrix than `false`s. (At least initially.) Wouldn't it make sense to rewrite it as a sparse matrix algorithm based on a list of `(x,y)` indexes where T[x][y] is `true`?

Comment: @biziclop your correct, in my real code I actually do it that way.  I just tried to post simple code here to convey the logic of my program.

Comment: Are there some bounds on your coefficients? In a quick think about it, it seems like you could have infinite answers when you have some valid coefficients on both a positive and negative value. Did I miss something?

Comment: @yakiimo in my real code yes I do have bounds but I felt it would over complicate my example so I didn't include it here(as I'm strictly trying to understand how to break the above algo into smaller parts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea would be to break out of the loop once you set `T[z][i]` to `true`, since you are only basically modifying `T[z][i]` here, and if it does become `true`, it won't ever be modified again.

```
for i = 1 to k
    for z = 0 to sum:
        for j = z-x_i to 0:
            if(T[j][i-1]): 
                T[z][i]=true;
                break;
```

EDIT2: Additionally, if I am getting it right, `T[z][i]` depends on the array `T[z-x_i..0][i-1]`. `T[z+1][i]` depends on `T[z+1-x_i..0][i-1]`. So once you know if `T[z][i]` is `true`, you only need to check one additional element (`T[z+1-x_i][i-1]`) to know if `T[z+1][i-1]` will be `true`.

Let's say you represent the fact whether `T[z][i]` was updated by a variable `changed`. Then, you can simply say that `T[z][i] = changed && T[z-1][i]`. So you should be done in two loops instead of three. This should make it much faster.

Now, to scale it - Now that `T[z,i]` depends only on `T[z-1,i]` and `T[z-1-x_i,i-1]`, so to populate `T[z,i]`, you do not need to wait until the whole `(i-1)`th column is populated. You can start working on `T[z,i]` as soon as the required values are populated. I can't implement it without knowing the details, but you can try this approach.

Comment: I kind of understand what you did(but don't understand how to scale it say I use a million variables and sum of a million), but I'm trying to break down the algo into multiple smaller parts so I can scale it across multiple cores.  I updated the question with code and what I'm seeing.

Comment: Did you understand the second part that I added (EDIT2).. I couldn't write the pseudo code for that because I don't understand how you populate T[0][i]. As for scaling, the difficulty is that each column is dependent on the previous one, so it's kinda difficult to apply divide and conquer..

Comment: I think I understand, its like a chicken/egg problem I can't figure out T[z][i] without knowing T[z+1-x_i..0][i-1]..I have updated the answer with the code I'm testing with.  I still don't understand how to scale this over multiple cpu's..do you think I might be looking at this wrong? maybe instead of thinking of how to turn the end result of T[z+1-x_i..0][i-1] to T[z][i], I should be trying to turn T[z][i] into T[z+1-x_i..0][i-1]?

Comment: Added an idea to scale it as well.. let me know how it works out

Comment: Thanks for the update, to be honest I don't fully understand how to decouple T[z,i] from the other two fully.  I have posted the full working code in my answer, is it possible to take a look and make suggestions from there?  For simplicity its in python but if you want I have java as well.

Comment: Ok.. I kinda understand what you are doing there.. but just clarify this.. d[:i+1] means d[0..i+1]? What is target_sum here? Are you looking for the linear combinations which would result in 10?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8547/discussion-between-raze2dust-and-learningjava)

Comment: Not sure where d[:i+1]..Your right I'm trying to find linear combinations which would result in 10(target_sum).  I have this in two phases, first is to build a lookup table(what I'm doing here and unable to scale) and second is to bring all together(which I am able to break down into smaller worker tasks).

Answer (score 0):

I take it this is something like unbounded knapsack? You can dispense with the loop over `c` entirely.

```
for i = 1 to k
    for z = 0 to sum
        T[z][i] = z >= x_i cand (T[z - x_i][i - 1] or T[z - x_i][i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the original example data you gave (linear combination of terms) and your answer to my question in the comments section (there are bounds), would a brute force approach not work?

```
c0x0 + c1x1 + c2x2 +...+ cnxn = SUM
```

I'm guessing I'm missing something important but here it is anyway:

**Brute Force Divide and Conquer:**

- main controller generates coefficients for say, half of the terms (or however many may make sense)
- it then sends each partial set of fixed coefficients to a work queue
- a worker picks up a partial set of fixed coefficients and proceeds to brute force its own way through the remaining combinations
- it doesn't use much memory at all as it works sequentially on each valid set of coefficients
- could be optimized to ignore equivalent combinations and probably many other ways

**Pseudocode for Multiprocessing**

```
class Controller
    work_queue = Queue
    solution_queue = Queue
    solution_sets = []
    create x number of workers with access to work_queue and solution_queue
    #say for 2000 terms:
    for partial_set in coefficient_generator(start_term=0, end_term=999):
        if worker_available(): #generate just in time
            push partial set onto work_queue
        while solution_queue:
            add any solutions to solution_sets
        #there is an efficient way to do this type of polling but I forget

class Worker
    while true: #actually stops when a stop work token is received
        get partial_set from the work queue
        for remaining_set in coefficient_generator(start_term=1000, end_term=1999):
            combine the two sets (partial_set.extend(remaining_set))
            if is_solution(full_set):
                push full_set onto the solution queue
```

Comment: Thank you very much Yakiimo, for taking the time to answer.I'll work on implementing your pseudocode to see how it works. Its a bit unclear , is it brute forcing the solution or the lookup table generation?  I understand the final result is dependent on all previous solutions but I'm trying to decouple the table generator from that requirement.  I updated my answer with another approach as well(if it gives any ideas) to building the table.

Comment: I guess that's where I got lazy and didn't try to interpret your other information. In the original problem definition, I don't see any reason for each solution being dependent on the previous solutions except perhaps for optimization purposes. That's why in my pseudocode coefficient sets are produced, calculated, and thrown away. There is no build up of any large sets of data. The largest item will be the set of solutions. Where are we disconnecting?

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer your question directly: it is brute forcing the solution by trying all possible sets of coefficients. The given values (x0,x1,...,xn) would be data somewhere and are only used in "is_solution()". The "coefficient_generator()" is literally a generator that produces one permutation of coefficients (c_start, ..., c_end) at a time. It should be straightforward to make both of those parts. Does that answer what you are asking? There is no table generation in my solution.